# Running a logger works fine in local project but fails on Heroku

Tags: python, django, logging, heroku

Running a module called `log.py` creates a file `my_file.log` where it logs at what time the script ran. Running `log.py` (over)writes to a log file perfectly fine in my local project but for some reason running it on my production deploy in heroku doesn't write to `my_file.log`. The `log.py` also does some other things and I can tell by that that `log.py` did indeed execute in Heroku. It's only the logs that aren't written.

First I thought it could be a permissions problem but checking with `ls -l` gives

```
drwx------ 3 my_app
-rw------- 1 my_file.log
```

The following is my project structure:

```
.
├── my_project
│   ├── my_app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   ├── my_file.log
│   │   └── management
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── commands
│   │           ├── __init__.py
│   │           └── log.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
└── requirements.txt
```

It shouldn't have anything to do with the code being used as a custom Django command because in my development version the log file is overwritten each time as it should.

This is the snippet in `log.py` responsible for logging to `my_file.log`:

```
log_lc = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 
  os.path.pardir, os.path.pardir, "my_file.log")
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_lc,level=logging.INFO,
  format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p',
  filemode="w")

logging.info("You just ran my_file.log")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku is read-only. You are trying to create your own log file, `my_file.log`, and you will not be able to do that since you cannot write anything to their file system.

You can, however, print log messages to Heroku's standard logs. [Here are the docs for that.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging). You could then check your messages via `heroku logs`.

In addition to Heroku's standard logging, they have many apps available for logging that you can install on your Heroku app. Otherwise, you could consider using an email option or writing your log file to a third party location like `s3`.

Comment: Why does the log file show it has write access: `-rw-------`?

Comment: I believe the files maintain the rights that they had on your machine and Heroku controls their read-only status via overlying permissions.

Comment: Aha, thanks! Do you know what their reason might be for not enabling write access? Just so pple would be forced to use Heroku bound apps?

Comment: Since they offer a free version, I'd imagine they would want to keep the footprint of each app as small as possible. They wouldn't want someone hosting an IMGUR or Instragram type app on their free hosting.